# Trigger cloud function on specific date and time firebase

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I want to change a document value at a specific date time in firestore, I don't want to use a scheduleFunctions of firebase i think it is costly to see every minute or an hour to check. Is there any better option which will trigger right on the given time etc.??. And it should be one time not a periodic call using flutter web and firebase for it

Comment: We used Cloud Tasks to achieve this. Its free for first 1 Million actions in case you care about the cost. https://medium.com/firebase-developers/how-to-schedule-a-cloud-function-to-run-in-the-future-in-order-to-build-a-firestore-document-ttl-754f9bf3214a

Answer (score 1):

You could use the [Google Cloud Scheduler](https://cloud.google.com/scheduler) to hit a HTTP Cloud Function periodically but using scheduled functions is your best bet.

Firebase had a very generous free tier. You mentioned you are “checking” every couple minutes or hours. That sounds like you updating a document based on an event, in which case you can use PubSub or Firestore triggered cloud functions.

Comment: i want to actually trigger the cloud function at a specific date and time not like a periodic task, it should be one time

Comment: You can always specify a cron job to run once a month on the given date and time, then delete the function after it happens. Alternatively you can write custom logic locally to invoke the http function at a given datetime.

Comment: it will be great help if you can share me some example link etc ?